# Can LinkedIn crawler read SPA pages?

Tags: angularjs, seo, web-crawler, linkedin-api, phantomjs

I am using PhantomJS along with the [Angular-seo package](https://github.com/steeve/angular-seo).

I managed to configure it to work with Facebook open-graph, but it seems that LinkedIn doesn't support the `_escaped_fragment_` format, and just ignores the route after the hasbang requesting the `index.html` page of the application instead of `myapp.com/?_escaped_fragment_=client_side_path`.

What can I do in order to resolve it?.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the only way to resolve this is to check the user agent of the bot and send them the static version. According to [this](http://www.botopedia.org/user-agent-list/social-media-agents/linkedin-bot.html), the user agent of the LinkedIn bot is this:

```
LinkedInBot/1.0 (compatible; Mozilla/5.0; Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1 +http://www.linkedin.com)
```

Comment: Yeah I figured this, but in my case I'm running a highly dynamic application, and serving a snapshot to the bot would be just inefficient compared to having a phantomJS instance running in the background.(or prerender.io for taht matter)

Comment: If you're serving content using PhantomJS and Angular-SEO already, you can just send over the same content over when the LinkedIn bot requests your site - so no extra work. Unless I'm misunderstanding something?

Comment: The LinkedIn bot, disregards of any URL parameters after the hahsbang, because from their point of view, anything after the hashbang mark is not in the HTTP spec(client side routing), so to begin with, the bot asks for the index.html file of the application, without any parameters(no escaped fragment).

Hope that it clarifies things for you

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use HTML5 mode with the fallback for older browsers? This means your urls will look normal, and google will request the full URL to your server with the `_escaped_fragment_` parameter present but empty.

Comment: Yes there is, the hashbang in the URL is what tells the google \ bing bots to make a request with an escaped fragment...
There is an alternative method of placing the hasbang in a meta tag, but it didn't work for me

Answer (score 1):

LinkedIn is not rendering JS and will only process the html static content of your SPA as of today.

As your application is highly dynamic, you could redirect LinkedIn crawler requests to an endpoint that will dynamically generate the required HTML for the LinkedIn crawler (e.g quick win: by using a CDN with a rules engine and serverless functions)

If you don’t need to feed the crawler with real-time information, you may consider using:

- a prerendering service (e.g. prerender.io)
- a static site generator to create prerendered pages of your SPA on your own